# Pycharm false import error alarm although code executes

Tags: python, pycharm, tensorflow

I am new to PyCharm IDE (accustomed to VS code).
I am getting an import error alarm on IDE with the following line of code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
Error: Cannot find reference 'keras' in '__init__.py'
```

But when I actually hit run, it perfectly prints the output without any error on IDE.

I am in a virtual env "/home/instantinopaul/.virtualenvs/tfcert/bin/python" (same in project interpreter settings) and it points to /usr/bin/python3.8

Tensorflow is installed in the virtual environment only and not  globally.

Version details:
Python version: 3.8
Tensorflow version: 2.9.0
PyCharm 2023.1 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-231.8109.197, built on March 29, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+10-b829.5 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.19.0-38-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1988M
Cores: 12
Registry:
debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
ide.experimental.ui=true

Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu?

Comment: It is ubuntu 22.04

Comment: This is a known [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53144) with tensorflow. Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71838765/13717851)

Comment: Sounds like you should use the Answer Your Own Question feature at the bottom of your question and make this an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue of auto-completion error for all IDEs (at-least for Vs code and pycharm) since tf 2.6 it seems. This happens because tensorflow loads keras via lazyloading fashion, which the IDEs cannot resolve.

Please check this issue thread on github [PyCharm doesn't resolve anything under tensorflow.keras](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53144)

There are two workarounds with this issue

1. [Try modify the file site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py near line 387](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53144#issuecomment-985179600)  mentioned on above thread.
2. Using `import keras.api._v2.keras as keras` since this seems to be the exact package tensorflow loads itself.